# Wifi iOS low level data harvesting

Tags: ios, signals, wifi

I am having trouble getting a straight answer.

I want to access iOS Wifi:
SSID
Channel
Frequency
Signal strength dBm
Lan Speed
Neighbor APs
Devices Connected to WLAN
did I miss any?

Apparently this URL is NOT for accessing the above:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper
This is for  NEHotspotHelper.
NEHotspotHelper is not for harvesting the low level data.

All Apple docs send folks to NEHotspotHelper and this is not the information for wifi harvesting.

My QUESTION is:
Where exactly is the specific documentation on how to harvest this low level data for iOS devices, please?

Comment: On a non-jailbroken device?  You can't.

Comment: there are many apps on the Apple store who have done it.  ANy ideas?

Comment: You can get the BSSID and SSID of the currently connected network via NEHotspotHelper - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork but you can't get signal strength, data rate, neighbour APs etc.

Comment: This app ( and many more ) obviously grab all the data:  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/oka-speed-test-wifi-signal/id1476136371       what do they know we don't?

Comment: That app doesn't grab *all the data* - It gets the RSSI, probably using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039848/getting-a-list-of-access-points-and-their-signal-strength)  The speed it reports is like any other speed test app - it transfers a known amount of data and works out how long it takes; That tells you the effective speed of the network between your device and their server, not the speed of the wifi connection.  To see other SSIDs you need the hotspot helper entitlement from Apple.

Comment: To get details on other devices on the LAN you need to use networking to try and connect to every address on the network.